# How to format brushed time axis (with context-dependent values)

Tags: date, d3.js, format, axis

I have an x axis with years 2009 - 2016 as tickValues. When I select a time period from the time widget, the tick Values become a combination of month names and years (thank you for this, d3!). So I have 'December, 2014, February' for example. Selecting an even narrower range gives me week names and dates e.g. 'June 14'.

[image]

I would like the month names to appear as the shortened format, e.g. Dec, Feb. I know this would be d3.time.format('%b'), but I can't set tickFormat to this without impacting the years as well (which all come out as 'Jan').

How do I apply a context-dependent tickFormat for d3 time scale axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for d3.time.format.multi:

For example:

```
var customTimeFormat = d3.time.format.multi([
  [".%L", function(d) { return d.getMilliseconds(); }],
  [":%S", function(d) { return d.getSeconds(); }],
  ["%I:%M", function(d) { return d.getMinutes(); }],
  ["%I %p", function(d) { return d.getHours(); }],
  ["%a %d", function(d) { return d.getDay() && d.getDate() != 1; }],
  ["%b %d", function(d) { return d.getDate() != 1; }],
  ["%b", function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }],
  ["%Y", function() { return true; }]
]);

//use the custom time format
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(customTimeFormat);
```

Here's a working JS fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/f5fgm9dt/8/

I found this to be helpful:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176

Comment: Thanks jkhan. For anyone reading this wishing to implement it, note that d3 version 2 and earlier versions of d3.v3 (such as version 3.3.9) do not support time.format.multi. Version 3.5.17 here does the trick https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js

Answer (score 1):

D3 achieves the adaptive behavior you describe — where it displays month or year depending on the value — using one of its own constructs: `d3.time.format.multi()`. That function, `multi()` expects an array of multiple time formatting options, and d3 picks the appropriate format based on a conditional associated with each format. That's how certain values, like the 1st day of the year, become a year tick and others become month ticks.

(NOTE: this in d3 3.x, which I'm guessing is what you're using. There's likely an equivalent in d3 4.x but I wasn't able to easily locate it in the 4.x API documentation, so more research would be needed if you're on 4.x.)

That multi-format function's [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#format_multi) provides the default implementation of that array of time formatting options, i.e. the implementation d3 uses by default with the time scale if you don't override it with your own formatting. It looks like this

```
var format = d3.time.format.multi([
  [".%L", function(d) { return d.getMilliseconds(); }],
  [":%S", function(d) { return d.getSeconds(); }],
  ["%I:%M", function(d) { return d.getMinutes(); }],
  ["%I %p", function(d) { return d.getHours(); }],
  ["%a %d", function(d) { return d.getDay() && d.getDate() != 1; }],
  ["%b %d", function(d) { return d.getDate() != 1; }],
  ["%B", function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }],
  ["%Y", function() { return true; }]
]);
```

So you can start by copy/pasting that default implementation into your own project, setting it as the tickFormat for your axis, and then tweak the values. Specifically, to answer your question then, you'll want to modify the 2nd-to-last element of that array, turning it into:

```
["%b", function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }] // from %B to %b
```

If your time axis happens to always span months or many days, you can also remove the first 4 or 5 elements of that array, since those formats will never come into play for long time spans.

In case this helps: If it's still not clear how the above array of formats and functions ends up having the effect it does, just imagine what `d` would be on the 1st of the year: it would have a `d.getMonth()` of `0` (because in javascript January is 0), and in fact that date would have zeros for all the methods used above `getMonth` (like `getDate`, `getHours` etc). So all those functions would return `0` which is `false` in javascript, and none of those formats would be used. Only the very last one would return `true` (because it's hard-coded to do so), and a year tick (`%Y`) will be displayed. Now, ticks at the 1st of any month other than January would have a non-zero `getMonth()` (but still zero for `getDay` etc), so the 2nd to last format would be used in those cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which is perfectly right. I received two near identical answers at the same time, and awarded the bounty to jkhan because he also showed how to apply the custom time format (via tickFormat). Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Can I ask you what happen when you want ti upgrade d3 to v4?? The example above doesn't work

Comment: @xargr I believe the modern implementation of this behavior is documented in [d3-time-format's README.md](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format), in the example that declares the function `multiFormat()`.